# Add a blank row to an R dataframe if a condition is met eleswhere in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, append, data-manipulation, data-management

File here: https://github.com/pb865/exmaplefile

These are data from a behavioral task where 30 and 31 under the event code (`ecode`) column refer to responses and any that are less than 30 are stimuli. For some trials, participants did not respond in time after target stimuli (20, 21, and 22 ecodes), and so there is no response code associated. However, I need to add in some blank rows and indicate explicitly that no response was made on that trial.

What I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
myevents = read.csv(data)

myevents2=myevents[myevents$ecode>=20 &  myevents$ecode<30 & lead(myevents$ecode<20),]
        
myrows = as.numeric(row.names(myevents2)
   
  for(i in 1:length(myrows)){
        myevents3 <- add_row(df, .after = i)
          }
```

```
myevents2=myevents[myevents$ecode>=20 &  myevents$ecode<30 & lead(myevents$ecode<20),]
        
        myrows=as.numeric(myevents2$item)
        
        myevents3=data.frame()
     
        
        for(i in 1:length(myevents$item)){
          if(myevents$item[i] %in% myrows){
            myevents3 <- add_row(myevents, .after=i)    
          }
        }
```

The final output should look the same, except with blank rows inserted after each of the rows in `myevents` that are included in the `myevents2` subset of data.

Neither of these worked.What happened instead was that it added a blank row in the 1st position where one was indicated to be placed, then stopped.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What output did you get or what error did you receive?

Comment: Please don't use share data with external links. It's better to include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions in the question itself. Make a smaller sample so it's more clear what needs to happen. Also note that adding "blank" lines to a data.frame is a bit odd. If you want special formatting for some output, you should focus on converting to desired output format rather than generating fake data.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")

# Find the index of each row that satisfies the ecode constraint
rows <- which(df$ecode < 30 & df$ecode >= 20)

# Find all the object classes for each column
column_classes <- sapply(df, class)

# Construct a blank row representative of the dataframe using the switch() function
blank_row <- as.data.frame(lapply(column_classes, function(class_type) {
  switch(class_type,
         "character" = "",
         "numeric" = NA_real_,
         "integer" = NA_integer_,
         "logical" = NA,
         "factor" = factor(levels = character(0)))
}), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# loop over rows inserting a blank row after every ith row
for (i in rows){
    df <- add_row(df, blank_row, .after = i + 1)
}
```

I agree with @MrFlick that adding in blank rows is odd. From what you've framed in the question it sounds like you want to make your dataframe more readable by explicitly noting that error codes  20 <= ecode < 30 are codes that represent stimuli with no response in a reasonable amount of time.

With that said I would suggest creating a new column to hold this data.

Comment: Thank you! I realize this is a strange request, but the constraints of the type of data preprocessing I'm working with require it to match another output file that has extra rows that correspond to trials which did not have a response, so I need to insert entire rows where there should be responses in this file, then denote them with a new code (e.g., 32). Once the rows are there, I know how to add them in, but I had trouble with just adding the rows in first.